# Go to activity explorer menu does not appear in eclipse when using Obeo UML designer 7.1

Tags: uml-designer

I installed the Obeo UML Designer 7.1.0.201611211357 from eclipse marketplace on Eclipse Neon.2 (4.6.2) platform (actually STS 3.8.3) and the menu Go to Activity Explorer does not appear when I right click on the uml model document from the Model Explorer in the Modeling perspective.  This is what I get:

[image]

And I expect:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems normal the activity explorer is linked to the project and not to the UML model. So you can find the Activity Explorer menu only on the project element from the model explorer.

Comment: Thanks.  I missed it as it is not too obvious but thanks for pointing it out.